# Socket.io Connection Event Not Triggering

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I am new to using socket.io and I have tried to set up a basic functionality according to the docs and youtube tutorials. My program is supposed to console log "New socket connection" when I navigate to the index page. However, the event is not triggering. Am I missing something? Thanks!

My app.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const socket = require("socket.io");
const http = require("http");
const moment = require("moment");

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socket(server);

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
// Set static folder
app.use("/public", express.static("public"));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Reached index page")
  res.render("index")
});

app.get('/room', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Reach room page")
  res.render("room")
});

// Run when a client connects
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New socket connection")
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running. Navigate to localhost:${PORT}`));
```

My index.ejs file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="icon" href="../public/">
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/index/css/index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <a href="/room">click here</a>

  <script>
    var socket = io(); // this line is supposed to be sufficient to trigger
                       // the socket connection
  </script>

  <script src="../routes/index.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, i have a really basic chat app like this one just check the code there could help you =) https://github.com/halilcakar/private-chat and the problem probably stands for where you create your socket instance you don't give any url to connect, it take's default `location.href` which is not the case all the time

Answer (score 0):

The error resulted from my naming my variable 'socket' when importing the socket.io dependency. The socket param in the line 'io.on("connection", (socket)' is supposed to reference another socket variable not the one that I created. Common practice is to name the dependency variable 'socketio' instead of 'socket'